# UFW firewall turns off after reboot

Tags: firewall

Ubuntu 20.04. UFW keeps turning off when the computer is shutting down. How do I keep it on at startup? I have used GUFW to set it, I have used CLI to enable it, but it keeps turning off.

Here is the output of `sudo ufw status`:

```
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip
Firewall is active and enabled on system startup
```

Comment: [Are you sure you enable it? `sudo ufw enable`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW#Enable_and_Disable). Add the output of `sudo ufw status verbose` to your post

Comment: Added verbose output to original post

Comment: Add what do you see to believe ufw is shut down?

Comment: I've the same problem too under Linux Mint 20.03

Answer (score -1):

Try waiting for a while when your computer is booting. UFW might be starting up.